# Laravel middlware 'only' fires for every route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

Whatever I do crud middlware is always fired. However it should only be fired if `$crud` array is declared and only for routes it contains. However this is not the case it fires every time. Even if I say `$crud = [];` However if I declare `['only' => ['route1', 'route2']]` then it works as expected.

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Routes which DO NOT load users notifications.
     * @var Array Routes without notifications.
     */
    public $notifications;
    /**
     * Routes which DONT require users account to be configured.
     * @var Array Routes needing configuration.
     */
    public $configured;
    /**
     * Routes which REQUIRE ownership of resource.
     * @var Array CRUD routes.
     */
    public $crud;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => $this->routes]);
        $this->middleware('configured', ['except' => $this->configured]);
        $this->middleware('notifications', ['except' => $this->notifications]);
        $this->middleware('crud', ['only' => $this->crud]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give a bit more information. Because as i see it, "except" will indeed fire except the routes defined. It is expected. If i understood wrongly, please further explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Laravel code it seems that when you use:

```
$this->middleware('crud', ['only' => []]);
```

Laravel will always use this middleware (for all Controller methods) so you should not middleware with empty `only` option.

So you should modify this contructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => $this->routes]);
    $this->middleware('configured', ['except' => $this->configured]);
    $this->middleware('notifications', ['except' => $this->notifications]);
    if ($this->crud) {
        $this->middleware('crud', ['only' => $this->crud]);
    }
}
```

and in child controllers that extend from `BaseController` you should do something like this in constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
   // here you set values for properties
   $this->routes = ['a','b'];
   $this->configured = ['c'];
   $this->notifications = ['d'];
   $this->crud = ['e','f'];

   // here you run parent contructor
   parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: I had the same thought about using 'only' with an empty array, but until now I could not find the location where middleware options are handled. could you provide a link to the corresponding source code please?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Look at `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher` - methods `getMiddleware` and `methodExcludedByOptions`

Comment: Thanks! Yours is definetely the right answer. ( already +1 by me ).  However I think, that the implemented behaviour is not optimal. In the Illuminate Source Code ! empty($options['only']) should be replaced with ! isset(...)  as in my oppinion "apply that middleware 'only' on 'nothing' ( empty array ) should be valid and not trigger that middleware at all

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I looked at it and you are correct. Has to be isset but also empty just has to skip on empty and on non instantiated. I did few tests and made a pull request into laravels framework github yesterday and it got merged so it should be updated now in latest revision.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess I was going to do the same in a free time :)